# loop cut then extrude into object

Tags: extrude

I try to loop cut 2 times on a cubic, then switch to front view, use box select to select the middle part, then extrude -1 around z axis into the cubic. but the output looks like below:
[image]

Obviously, the two border face not been extruded as expected. I know boolean modify works for this case but I wish to use extrude.

Comment: "*face not been extruded as expected*" This is the expected result. what did you wish to see? Blender erasing those faces for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Rip Fill (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) on both edges, you can use vertex snap tool to help the edges Z positioning,

[image]

you could also do both together (start with cursor between edges)

[image]

remember to remove doubles, after.

Answer (score 3):

If i understood the question are you looking for this. No need to remove doubles or delete extra mesh. This addon do the best.

[image]

With the Default cube sub divide it twice. With the edge selected scale to Y axis. Select the top 3 Faces and with the Destructive Extrude [Addon](https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX#) 
Push it downwards. Holding control key you can align with the edges.